How to make ubuntu VM screen properly full size on Windows host?
I am having problems the whole day with VirtualBox 7.1.2 on windows 10 and ubuntu 24.04 guest, so here is my next issue popping up just like that without any change in the graphical settings.
Suddenly, the VM screen only occupies a small portion of the windows screen:

How to fix that? How to make the guest screen occupy the whole windows screen again?

When I do "View" -> "Auto size Guest Display" it makes the windows screen smaller, but not the VM screen larger. When I then click on full screen, I am back to the original problem.
When I do "View" -> "Adjust window size" it makes the windows screen smaller, but not the VM screen larger. When I then click on full screen, I am back to the original problem.
When I do "View" -> "Virtual Screen 1" -> "resize to " then nothing happens.

So is there a way how to change the screen resolution of the guest?
Current settings for "Display":

I have installed the GuestAdditions and here is how the VM is configured (and how it did work this morning ...):

Base memory: 14 GB
Chipset: PIX3
TPM: None
Processor: 4
Execution Cap: 100%
PAE/Nx disabled
Nested VT-x/AMD-v disabled
Video Memory: 128 MB
Graphics Controller: VMSVGA
3d Acceleration disabled

The host information:

hp EliteBook 840 GB
Windows 10 10.0.19045 Build 19045
RAM: 32 GB
i7-1185G7 processor (4 cores)
VirtualBox 7.1.2
Linux Guest Additions are installed

Display info:
Name    Intel(R) Iris(R) Xe Graphics
PNP Device ID   PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_9A49&SUBSYS_880D103C&REV_01\3&11583659&2&10
Adapter Type    Intel(R) Iris(R) Xe Graphics Family, Intel Corporation compatible
Adapter Description Intel(R) Iris(R) Xe Graphics
Adapter RAM 1.00 GB (1’073’741’824 bytes)
Installed Drivers   C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\iigd_dch.inf_amd64_da775d7ecf291310\igdumdim64.dll,C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\iigd_dch.inf_amd64_da775d7ecf291310\igd10iumd64.dll,C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\iigd_dch.inf_amd64_da775d7ecf291310\igd10iumd64.dll,C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\iigd_dch.inf_amd64_da775d7ecf291310\igd12umd64.dll
Driver Version  31.0.101.4887
INF File    oem310.inf (iTGLD_w10_DS section)
Color Planes    Not Available
Color Table Entries 4294967296
Resolution  1920 x 1080 x 60 hertz
Bits/Pixel  32
Memory Address  0x3E000000-0x3EFFFFFF
Memory Address  0x0000-0xFFFFFFF
I/O Port    0x00003000-0x0000303F
IRQ Channel IRQ 4294967243
Driver  C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERSTORE\FILEREPOSITORY\IIGD_DCH.INF_AMD64_DA775D7ECF291310\IGDKMDN64.SYS (31.0.101.4887, 48.40 MB (50’748’616 bytes), 27.11.2023 13:23)

I HONESTLY think there is either a major bug in VirtualBox 7.1.2 or in ubuntu 24.04!

You can try changing the resolution by following these steps:

Open the Settings app on your VM.
[

Click Display at the left side of the settings app menu.

Change the resolution.



First, there is no option for resolution. Second, as I mentioned I DID NOT CHANGE ANYTHING related to the Display settings.

@Alex That's very strange, I had it working on the settings app on my ubuntu VM

See the updated question, I added a screenshot of the current settings I see ...

@Alex That's not the settings app I am talking about, I am saying that the one inside Ubuntu, not Virtualbox.

Oh I see. But it seems the solution was to change the "Graphics Controller" of the VirtualBox Settings actually... I just saw now there was an invalid setting reported (see the screenshot I made).

@Alex I had updated my answer to show an image of the settings app. You should be able to use that to change the resolution.
